# onblur and clique button problem?

Tags: asp.net

i have a probleme with mytextbox , i have a button and textbox with onblur and onfocus event it works fine but after i type text and i clique button the onblur event is handled wich is an error i want to save my text not the oblur message , that s mean how i can distinct between clique button and onblur event for my textbox  also when i clique in page and textbox is not empty (theres a text) the oblur event is handled , i dont know how to manage my event and where i should place them

thanks

Comment: Can you post your code, so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd need to see a sample of the code to understand a little more what it is actually doing in order to answer your question.  Can you post a short segment to demonstrate the problem?